# Configure Apache to show file sorted by Name

Tags: apache, wamp

How can i configure Apache [WAMP] to show file sorted by name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to enable `Indexes`.

```
<Directory /path/to/directory>
    Options +Indexes
 </Directory>
```

Comment: Create a .htaccess file, put `Options +Indexes` inside. If it doesn't work, your `httpd.conf` needs to enable `AllowOverride`.

Comment: i use htaccess for ErrorDocument, after writing this option it is showin ERROR 500 :(